# Button EventHandler in form

Tags: c#, events, delegates

The button which we can create on the form is written in terms of event handler in Form1.Designer.cs as

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

Here `Click` is `public event EventHandler` 's type and this `EventHandler` is a delegate as

```
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Now,

why can't it be '='(equals)

```
this.button1.Click = new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

and also when I am passing the argument `this.button1_Click`, how does it match up to
 `void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);` delegate ? As here I have two arguments.

Please clear me with this.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ttSo, let's see what event is.

Code, you are write

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

will compile to

```
private EventHandler MyEvent = null;

[MethodImp(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public void add_MyEvent(EventHandler value) {
    MyEvent = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine(MyEvent, value);
}

[MethodImp(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public void remove_MyEvent(EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs> value) {
    MyEvent = (EventHandler)Delegate.Remove(MyEvent, value);
}
```

So, as you see, you cannot directly access to delegate and can only call += and -=, which is overridden for event class.
Also you can manually manage this mechanism by overriding methods += and -=. 
You can do it like this:

```
public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
   add { //your code for += here }
   remove { //your code for -= here }
}
```

More about event and delegates you can read in book "CLR via C#". I found all of this in this book.

Comment: And of course answer for your second question is: when you do new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
You aren't create a EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e), you just create method which has the same arguments and return type as EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e).

Answer (score 1):

esentially, you are adding a handler to the event, not setting the one handler.  you might want to have more handlers for an event.  one handler should not preclude having other handlers because there might be multiple actions that you could want to take place in response to a single event that might happen in different classes and in different places and on different threads and under different conditions.  += says make me a subscriber to this  event (and potentially one subscriber among many).

Answer (score 1):

What if you want to have multiple methods called on Click event. What you are doing with

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

is registering for this.button1_Click method to be invoked when Click event is raised. `+=` adds handler and NOT assigns handler.

Answer (score 0):

1/ it can not be '='(equals) because delegate is like a function pointer
2/ If you want to pass parameter to event button click, you have to make your own button class and implement Click event and have you own EventArgs

sample code:

```
public class MyEventArg
{
    int _param1;
    string _param2;
    //you can add more param
    public MyEventArg(int _param1,string _param2)
    {
        this._param1 = _param1;
        this._param2 = _param2;
    }
}

public delegate void MyButtonClickHandler(object sender, MyEventArg e)
public class MyButton:Control
{
     public event MyButtonClickHandler OnMyClick;
     //You can raise your event here
 protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
 {
           MyEventArg e = new MyEventArg(1,"a");//just sample data here
           this.OnMyClick(this,e);
     }
}
```

In the form that contains MyButton class instant

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MyButton myButton = new MyButton();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myButton.OnMyClick += new MyButtonClickHandler(this.myButton_OnMyClicked);
    }

    private void myButton_OnMyClicked(object sender, MyEventArg e){
    //your implementation        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear Nagaraj Tantri,

For question 1: As said above, Due to **Delegate** can set up multi-event.

For question 2:As culithay said, if you want to pass custom arguments throug event buttion

click, if you want to use **EventHandler** and pass cutom own argument

you have to custom your control class and custom own event argument,

the custom event parameter **CustomEventArg** should inherit **EventArg** class.

You can take the sample code as below.

```
// Customs ColorChanged's event parameter.     
public class ColorChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private Color color;
    public ColorChangedEventArgs(Color c)
    {
        color = c;
    }

    public Color GetColor
    {
        get { return color; }
    }
}


    //Add this method in your custom control
    protected void ibtnTest_Click(object sender, ColorChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO;
    }
```

You can also referen MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)